# Is "+" a two-place predicate?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, foundations

In Volume I of [Fundamentals of Mathematics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-volume-1), Edited by H. Behnke, F. Bachmann, K. Fladt, W. Süss and H. Kunle, it is stated that **"[T]he function sign '+' is a two-place predicate"**.

To me, a predicate is a statement which takes one or more arguments (subjects) and evaluates to either true or false.  The authors have been careful not to restrict the discussion to so-called "classical logic". So, perhaps there is some alternate mathematical universe in which "1+1" has a truth value.  But I know of none.

I don't believe the authors give a concrete definition of the term *predicate*, so I'm kind of at a loss for a means of assessing the validity or reliability of this assertion.

The principal author of the chapter in question is [Hans Hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Hermes), so I am not wont to blithely dismiss its content.

**Is it generally accepted that a function symbol such as "+" is a predicate?**

---

Edit to add: in computer programming "1+1" often does have a truth value.  Namely "true". But in that context "0+0" is false.

Comment: More context needed: Is this "$+$" being used as an addition opertator or as conjunction in a boolean algebra?

Comment: The context is conventional arithmetic.

Comment: No, the word "predicate" is not correct. It appears this book was translated from German, so it is hard to know if the error was in the original or if it came in with the translation.

Comment: Given that Hermes, in his *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, assigns the usual meanings to "predicate symbol" and "function symbol," you are likely seeing a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right; it is not usual to call + a predicate.

Either the book you're quoting is using  very nonstandard terminology, or it's a typo.

Comment: Your answer is probably the best possible, but I'm going to sit on it for a bit before I accept it.  Perhaps someone else will have an answer we haven't foreseen.

Comment: Apparently the non-standard usage was intended.  I lost track of the exact reference in subsequent discussion.  If, upon review, I find the confirming statement, I will share a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that + is a predicate.  Then it takes two truth values and returns a truth value (note that I didn't say true or false, I'm NOT assuming conventional two-valued logic).  Now, the context consists of conventional arithmetic, so let's suppose the natural numbers instead of the integers (the integers end up worse to try to make '+' into a predicate).  It sounds reasonable to me to say that 0 could represent the most false proposition.  But, since there does not exist a greatest natural number, every single instance of +(x, y) yields a truth value which is less than some other truth value.  Consequently, there is no greatest truth value.  That wholly flies in the face of conventional multi-valued and infinite-valued logic where there exists a greatest truth value, and at least sometimes or maybe always it gets supposed there exists a greatest truth value in classical logic also.

So, at the very least, I don't see how someone could plausibly maintain '+' as a predicate.  It either leads to a paradox of there not existing a greatest truth value and there existing a greatest truth value, or it needs such a radical concept of logic that it seems difficult to see how it could work.